# What is the intuition behind the sum of the inverse values of the resistors in a parallel circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

I wish to understand in the area of parallel circuits *why* this formula works:
$$\frac{1}{R_T} = \frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2} + \frac{1}{R_3} + \cdot\cdot\cdot+$$

in particular what is the meaning of $\frac{1}{R_x}$. I understand that it derives from
\begin{align}
I_T &= I_1 + I_2 + I_3 \\
\frac{V}{R_{t}} &= \frac{V}{R_1} + \frac{V}{R_2} + \frac{V}{R_3} \\
\frac{V}{R_{t}} &= V \left(\frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2} + \frac{1}{R_3}\right)
\end{align}
and so I know *how* it works. But I'm trying to intuitively understand what is the meaning of the sum of the inverse values of the individual resistors in a parallel circuit. I'm not looking for a mathematical explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The resistance $R = \frac{U}{I}$.

The inversed resistance $G = \frac{1}{R} = \frac{I}{U}$ is the  [electrical conductance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistance_and_conductance) .

Resistances are additive in serial scenarios, as voltages  at the same current are additive.

$$R_\mathrm{T} = \frac{U_\mathrm{T}}{I} = \frac {U_1 + U_2 + U_3}{I} = \frac{U_1}{I} + \frac{U_2}{I} + \frac{U_3}{I} = R_1 + R_2 + R_3$$

Conductances are additive in parallel scenarios, as currents at the same voltage are additive.

$$G_\mathrm{T} = \frac{I_\mathrm{T}}{U} =  \frac{I_1 + I_2 + I_3}{U} =  \frac{I_1}{U} + \frac{I_2}{U} + \frac{I_3}{U} = G_1 + G_2 + G_3$$

If there are parallel resistors 1 Ohm, 2  Ohm, 5  Ohm,  they have the respective conductances 1 S, 0.5 S, 0.2 S, with the summary conductance 1.7 S, which is equivalent to the resistance 1/1.7 Ohm.

For $n$ general resistors:

$$R_\mathrm{T} = \frac 1{G_\mathrm{T}} = \frac {1}{ \sum_{i=1}^{n} G_i } = \frac {1}{ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{R_i} }$$

It is valid even for other passive components like capacitors and inductors, if the respective complex arithmetic and generalized quantities impedance (complex resistance) and admittance (complex conductance) are involved.

---

Few analogies:

1. Imagine your car fuel tank has a leaking hole with some flow resistance and gasoline flows out of the tank. Does it helps to slow down leaking if you punch out many other holes ?
2. If the above tank is leaking at one place, does it help to totally stop leaking if it does not leak on other places at all ?
3. An insulated wire is a parallel connection of the wire and its insulation. If their resistance were additive, you could not use insulated wires to conduct electricity.

Comment: And why can't the total resistance just be the sum of the individual resistors? i.e $R_t = R_1 + R_2 + R_3$?

Comment: That's the case for multiple resistors in series. In a series connection, the voltages add and the current is the same. In a parallel connection, the voltage is the same and the currents add.

Comment: @quadratic sphere Why do you have a fixation of resistance? For series connection you add the inverse of conductances. Do you have a problem with this? For parallel conection you add the conductances. Adding the inverseses of resistances is the same as adding conductances. The answer above explains exacyly "why" is this way.